# embedded jquery script not executing with html

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery embedded in my html page which takes the value of `cgstPct` and price fields and calculates the value of the final amount on the change event of `cgstPct` field.
On the web page this does not work.

I tried running on jsfiddle and it worked there so I assume there might be a problem with how I'm using it in my HTML file.

```
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <head>
        <title>Create Product</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
        $('#cgstPct').change(function() {
            var pct = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
            var total = (price) * (pct/100);
            $('#finalAmount').val(total.toFixed(2));
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div layout:fragment="content" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8">
                <h3>
                    <a href="/product" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Product</a>
                </h3>
                <h2>Create Product</h2>
                <form action="/save">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="prodName" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="prodDesc" cols="60" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Product Price</label>
                        <input type="number" id="price" class="form-control" name="prodPrice" />

                    <label for="cgstPct">CGST PCT</label>
                    <input type="number" id="cgstPct" class="form-control" name="cgstPct" />

                    <label for="finalAmount">Amount after GST</label>
                    <input type="number" readonly="readonly" id="finalAmount" class="form-control" name="finalAmount" />

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to give **script tag** to your code.Can you please change your code structure as per below.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $('#cgstPct').change(function() {
            var pct = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
            var total = (price) * (pct/100);
            $('#finalAmount').val(total.toFixed(2));
        });
 </script>
```

And for better practice always write your jquery or javascript code at bottom of **body tag**. This might solve your problem .Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't have code inside a script tag that has a src.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js">
  $('#cgstPct').change(function() {
    var pct = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
    var total = (price) * (pct/100);
    $('#finalAmount').val(total.toFixed(2));
  });
</script>
```

It should be

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#cgstPct').change(function() {
    var pct = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var price = parseFloat($('#price').val());
    var total = (price) * (pct/100);
    $('#finalAmount').val(total.toFixed(2));
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.After making the suggested change had to also include the script part in the body and it worked.